# Enable Safari Zoom by Script

Tags: safari, applescript, zoom

I've got a WQHD (1440p) Monitor hooked up to my 13 inch MacBook Pro when I'm sitting at my desk. Love the high resolution (much screen real estate) but sometimes I find myself toggling Safari's Zoom to 125%:
[image]

Is there an option to toggle this setting by Script/Terminal Command or else automatically? If so I could toggle it automatically when connecting the monitor with [Control Plane](https://www.controlplaneapp.com).

This code gets to the right settings tab, but I can’t figure out how to set the zoom level:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "," using command down
        delay 1
        tell window 1
            click button "Advanced" of toolbar 1 of it
            delay 1
            keystroke "w" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Is Cmd/+ not doing what you need?

Comment: cmd + / cmd + - does not sets the default zoom for all pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Applescript code sets the zoom level globally:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "," using command down
        delay 0.5
        tell window 1
            click button "Advanced" of toolbar 1 of it
            click pop up button 3 of group 1 of group 1 of it
            click menu item 4 of menu 1 of pop up button 3 of group 1 of group 1 of it
            keystroke "w" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

change `menu item 4` to `5` for a 115% or `6` for 125% zoom level.

Using an Applescript is better than using `cmd +` / `cmd + -` because it sets the default zoom for all pages.